# How to implement sub-routes

Tags: go, gorilla

I want to achieve routes like

`user/profile`

`user/cart`

`user/products`

Currently, I'm doing this

```
r.HandleFunc("user/signup", signupHandler).Methods("POST")
r.HandleFunc("user/signin", signinHandler).Methods("POST")
r.HandleFunc("user/profile", profileHandler).Methods("GET")
r.HandleFunc("user/cart", cartHandler).Methods("POST")
r.HandleFunc("user/products", productsHandler).Methods("GET")
```

As you can see these routes starts with `user` so can how can I know it's a `user` routes so I can send handle it in a different file.

I want something like

```
r.HandleFunc("user/", handlerWhichHandelAllTheRequestFromUser)
```

It should handle all the URL which starts from `users`.

I'm using mux gorilla

Comment: You can use regular expressions in mux routing: `s.HandleFunc("/articles/{category}/{id:[0-9]+}", ArticleHandler)`

Comment: If this is gorilla/mux, you can use a subrouter: `userRouter:=r.Path("/user").Subrouter()`

Comment: It is. It is. `gorilla/mux` Thank you!

Comment: If it were `net/http`, then  exactly the code you posted would work exactly like intended. The stdlib router treats routs with a trailing slash as prefix handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PathPrefix function in mux. You can use it to make the path prefix i.e. "/user" in this case.

example:-

userHandler.go

```
func makeUserHandler()http.Handler{
  //Define all you handlers here
  r := mux.NewRouter()
  r.HandleFunc("user/signup", signupHandler).Methods("POST")
  r.HandleFunc("user/signin", signinHandler).Methods("POST")
  r.HandleFunc("user/profile", profileHandler).Methods("GET")
  r.HandleFunc("user/cart", cartHandler).Methods("POST")
  r.HandleFunc("user/products", productsHandler).Methods("GET")
  return r
}
```

main.go

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.PathPrefix("/user").Handler(makeUserHandler())
```

Please make necessary changes to the above code as per your requirement.

Comment: So how will I know about which is it? It's `signup` or 'signin' inside `makeUserHandler`?

Comment: When prefix path is matched in main.go it will forward it to the makeUserHandler router. From there that router will match its path i.e. "/signup" or "/signin" and call the  appropriate handler i.e. signupHandler or signinHandler.